# Is this a issue associated with Ready to Program Java or is it a syntax error? (Object Error)

Tags: java, class, object

Within this program I am creating an class instance.

I am trying to make a void method to display the person's (objects) attributes outside of the main method.

The errors are:

**1.**'*No field name size was found in People*' (5)

**2.**'*No method called DisplayAtt was found in People*' (20)

Im wondering if this is an error asociated with my program or the general syntax of RTP.

I am trying to learn OOP.

```
class People
    {
        public void DisplayAtt ()
        {
            System.out.println (size);
            System.out.println (race);
            System.out.println (personality);
        }


        public static void main (String args[])
        {
            Person thisPerson;
            thisPerson = new Person ();

            thisPerson.size = "Average";
            thisPerson.race = "Caucasian";
            thisPerson.personality = "Stubborn";

            thisPerson.DisplayAtt ();
        }
    }

    /// Object Class ///


    public class Person
    {
        String size;
        String race;
        String personality;

    }
```

Comment: the problem is with your code. The Person class does not have the DisplayAtt() method. It's in the People class

Comment: Place the `DisplayAtt()` method in the `Person` class. And please follow the Java naming conventions in the future, and have methods start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display att needs to be a method in your Person class or needs to accept a person as aparameter.

Answer (score 0):

Move `DisplayAtt` to `Person` not People.

Normally you would override `toString()` using your IDE to generate the code.